# Levenberg Marquardt in calibration opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration, levenberg-marquardt

I tried to understand Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm implementation in OpenCv Camera Calibration.
In W.Burger's paper-> [here](http://staff.fh-hagenberg.at/burger/publications/reports/2016Calibration/Burger-CameraCalibration-20160516.pdf)

I saw [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCcet.jpg) Matrix in page 24.

So what does    theoretically mean of this matrix' each cell?

And how it implemented in openCv code.

Comment: Do you have any problem in implementing something, or you want SO to google explanation or code for you? On the same page, explanation for what each cell and row means, is given.

Comment: I just wondered how the expression implements on code. And where it be implemented?

Comment: I just wondered how the expression is in each cell implements on code. And where it be implemented in openCV calibration module as a code? And I couldn't see enough explanation to understand. I know w, a, X, P() and p() means.

Answer (score 0):

Levenberg Marquardt is a classical algorithm for non-linear optimization. OpenCV indeed uses it for camera calibration. One should understand the algorithm in general before diving into its usage in OpenCV.
Specifically, the matrix that you've pointed out is the Jacobian, a generalization of one dimensional derivative to multidimensional function.